# gedit "lagging"

Tags: gedit

whenever I use gedit, the program lags when I switch lines with the mouse or enter/backspace. It only started doing this in the past month and I have no idea why. A bit of background, I'm using my college's lab PCs and I have this issue on all PCs that I log in to. Here are some examples of what I mean by lagging. Lets say I have

```
int main(){
   int something;

return 0;
}
```

as the base. Now if I move my curser in front of "return 0" and hit enter a few times I get:

```
int main(){
    int something;


return 0;
```

notice how it got rid of the closing `}` BUT it didn't ACTUALLY get rid of it, once I click anywhere else on the file, gedit "catches up" and adds the `}` so its visible again. Now lets say I want to backspace from this, to bring `return 0;` back up. Now I get:

```
int main(){
    int something;

return 0; <-- where return 0 ACTUALLY is
|return 0; <-- where | is the little curser thing just stuck there, not blinking
}
```

Again once I click somewhere else it eventually fixes itself. I get problems when trying to switch between tabs too, it takes a while and freezes up for a bit. I haven't installed any new plugins or anything since the last time it was working perfectly, so I don't know why this is happening all of a sudden. Any suggestions for how I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to put a concise question at beginning then add the details, because people may not read through it

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and Gedit are you using?